# How do you in C# read a text file for a specific string, and if it doesnt exist write it

Tags: c#, file, text, filestream

I know how to read append and write with Streamreader/Steamwriter.  But I am having issues with getting my program to read the text file and check for a specific string of data.  If it doesnt exist write it at the end.  Any Ideas?  Im trying to do this to a specific file, via web page button using Server.MapPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you read file and check

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path));
{
    string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();

    if (contents.Contains(//string to check//))
    {
       appendtofile("add string")
    }
}
```

and here is how you append

```
public void appendtofile(string text)
{


   using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
        {
            sw.WriteLine(text);

        }

}
```